# What does "'Copy Job' would like to control this computer using accessibility features" mean?

Tags: security, privacy, accessibility

Since installing OS X 10.9, I periodically get a message that

```
'Copy Job' would like to control this computer using accessibility features
```

I believe the source is [SuperDuper!](http://www.shirt-pocket.com/SuperDuper/SuperDuperDescription.html) (2.7.1), but am unsure what it is asking for, whether to allow it, and what the consequences of denying would be.

Comment: Is this message in a window or is the above a copy from terminal or one of the logs in console?

Comment: @Deesbek: It appears in a window (dialog).

Comment: and... you are running Mac OS X 10.8.? and SuperDuper! 2.7.1?

Comment: @Deesbek: Fixed.

Comment: I just did a quick search on google and there are no real answers, http://superuser.com/q/657015/261896. I would send an email to support@shirt-pocket.com. Personally I would deny it. However if you are keen for some experimentation I would run `opensnoop -n SuperDupper!.app` then allow it, stop the opensnoop process and see what was being accessed by SuperDuper!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a post on Dave Nanian's (the author of SuperDuper!) blog at http://www.shirt-pocket.com/blog/index.php/shadedgrey/comments/mavericks/ which explains this issue:

> As you may know, our scheduling feature runs a little application called "Copy Job" behind the scenes...
>
> For some reason, in Mavericks, this check (and a second one that checks whether Growl is running) now generates a scary security warning...
>
> We've found a way around this prompt, but it requires that you delete and recreate your existing schedules...